# Java project,running on tomcat cannot connect to mysql server database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I have .war file with java project. When it run, the project should fill existing database by tables. All settings for database access  are correct(login,password and port). But when project running, tables are not creating. Also I dont have any access to source code of the project, only .war file.
I am using ubuntu 14.04. 
I think problem is in permissions, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: some traces or logs please?

Comment: Check the permission of user in mysql.

Comment: I set up all permissions for tomcat7 user, but it still didnt working. 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tomcat7'@'127.0.0.1';
Maybe it is wrong user?